# Why doesn't Ajax.BeginForm execute javascript code in callback if InsertionMode is InsertBefore or InsertAfter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

When using `Ajax.BeginForm`, if the `InsertionMode` is set to `Replace`, when the MVC View is returning a PartialView containing some javascript code, the code is executed.

But when the `InsertionMode` is `InsertAfter` or `InsertBefore`, the script isn't executed.

Is it by design? Or a bug?

Here's the code :

```
 <h2>Ajax Form Call action</h2>
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PartialDisplay", "Test",
 new AjaxOptions
 {
     HttpMethod = "POST",
     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
     UpdateTargetId = "PartialResult"
 }))
 {
     <input type="submit" value="Go" />
 }

<div id="PartialResult"></div>
```

And the code of the PartialView :

```
<p>Partial view</p>

<script>
    alert('executed script!');
</script>
```

I tried with a simple ajax call, but it is working with both `insertBefore` and `Replace` (sort of 'Replace') :

```
function DisplayPartial() {
    // call action
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Test/PartialDisplay',
        dataType: "html", // expected response datatype
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {

            $(data).insertBefore($('#PartialResult')); // insertBefore (Works)
            $('#PartialResult').html(data);            // sort of "Replace" (Works too)
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('error:' + xhr.error);
        }
    });
}
```

---

I've done some other tries, and here's a table which shows when the js code is executed, and when it is not :

```
"Way to fill a div                               |  is JS executed?
--------------------------------------------------------------
Ajax.BeginForm   InsertionMode.Replace             Yes
Ajax.BeginForm   InsertionMode.InsertAfter         No
Ajax.BeginForm   InsertionMode.InsertBefore        No

jQuery           .insertBefore                     Yes
jQuery           .insertAfter                      Yes
jQuery           .prepend                          Yes
jQuery           .append                           Yes
jQuery           .html (replace)                   Yes

Vanilla JS       .innerHTML                        No
Vanilla JS       .outerHTML                        No
```

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views

Comment: @Stephen : That not really the point here, but yeah, I almost agree with you. But sometimes, when displaying a partialview, you need to update some js variable, or call some piece of code to update something like `lastElementRetrievedId = 155` or `UpdateSomething();`. I'm not talking about adding proper JS code in a partialview, but just calling come code, exactly like `Ajax.BeginForm` is calling `SomethingOnComplete()` when it has done the post.